# Como centro horizontalmente el icono de pregunta rojo?

Tags: html, css, icono

Ya probé de varias formas y no logro centrarlo horizontalmente.

Aclaro que recién estoy empezando con CSS.

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudar.

[image: Centrar icono rojo]

Dejo el código acá:

https://jsfiddle.net/Chakl22/L7rtzj18/12/

Comment: El código debe ir como texto en la pregunta. No en un enlace externo.

Comment: Prueba con display flex o grid en el css

Comment: @Jacobo Lo tuve que poner asi por que no me dejaba crear la publicacion, me decia "La publicacion parece tener solo codigo". Y no era asi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar [`vertical-align: sub;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) y quitar `display: inline-block;` y `text-align:center !important;`

Ejemplo:

```css
body {
    background-color: #141622;
}

.obtener-creditos {
    background-color: #1f2535 !important;
    color: orange;
    border: solid;
    margin: 8px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}

.obtener-creditos h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: large;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: auto;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #616161;
}

.obtener-creditos h1:before {
    content: url('https://api.iconify.design/akar-icons/question-fill.svg?color=%23e10000&width=18');
    padding-right: 2px;
    vertical-align: sub;
}

.obtener-creditos p:before {
    content: url('https://api.iconify.design/fa-solid/hand-point-right.svg?color=%2392b700');
    font-family: 'Material-Design-Iconic-Font';
    color: #c3b400;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.obtener-creditos span:before {
    content: url('https://api.iconify.design/fa-solid/coins.svg?color=%23c3b400');
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    color: #c3b400;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jijo de...</title>
    <!--Google Font-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    <script src="//code.iconify.design/1/1.0.6/iconify.min.js"></script>
    <!--Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>       
            <div class="obtener-creditos">
                <h1>Como obtener bla, bla...:</h1>
    
                <p>1 Tema = <span>2 bla,bla...</span></p>
                <p>1 Post = <span>1 bla,bla...</span></p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!